# Using hugo debug utils with Justice template

Tags: html, hugo

Following the README.md in the downloaded hugo-debug-utils-main/ directory I ran

```
hugo mod get github.com/atishay/hugo-debug-utils
```

Now I want to install the module for debugging my developing web site using the Justice theme. The README.md file says,

````
Add in your template.

```go-html-template
{{- partial "debug/debug.html" (dict "context" .) -}}
```
````

In which directory should I be when I run this command?

TIA,

Rich

Answer (score 0):

> In which directory should I be when I run this command?

The first one in the root of your project. The second one should be part of your template (layouts/_default/single.html or layouts/index.html).